# UK Date issue in java script date object

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have the below code. If we try to retrieve the day, month and year in UK server setup. The date object returns an incorrect value.

```
var startDate = "30/08/2013"; 
var d = new Date(startDate); 
alert(d.getFullYear()); //2015
```

Please help me

Comment: you forgot the code ;)

Comment: var startDate="30/08/2013";
var d = new Date(startDate);
alert(d.getFullYear());//2015

Comment: Please update the code in the question i cannot do it....

Comment: Give me any answer. why the uk server setup the date time year is increased while date is "30/08/2013" to something like "../../2015"

Comment: Use `var startDate = "08/30/2013";` ~ "months/days/years". Else with "30/08/2013" you set 30months + 8 days+ 2013years = June 8th 2015. Or use this additional javascript: `var startDate = "30/08/2013"; var s = startDate.split('/'); startDate = s[1]+'/'+s[0]+'/'+s[2]; alert(d); //2013`

Comment: Interestingly for me (in chrome) the code in the question alerts "NaN" (http://jsfiddle.net/dYuvS/)

Comment: thanks, I need to write convert date time code dynamic format because, Site is running uk(30/08/2013),india(30-08-2013),US(08/30/2013) etc.,. I would like to globalized US format. Please help me...

Comment: One thing to note: The Server has no impact on the result of the Date() object as client-side code... unless you're developing on Node.js. Date() is inherently US format dates. Date() is reliant on your system clock. If your system clock says 2015, your Date() says 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) if you want better control of parsing:

```
var startDate = "30/08/2013"; 
var m = moment(startDate,"DD/MM/YYYY");
alert(m.year()); //2013
```

Comment: +1 because OP asked for globalization (internationalisation)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the date as a list of arguments instead:

```
var startDate = "30/08/2013"; // Would also work with 30-08-2013
var startDateArray;

if(startDate.contains('/'))        
    startDateArray = startDate.split('/');
else if (startDate.contains('-'))
    startDateArray = startDate.split('-');
else if (startDate.contains('.'))
    startDateArray = startDate.split('.');

var d = new Date(startDateArray[2], startDateArray[1]-1, startDateArray[0]); // Month is 0 based, that's why we are subtracting 1
```

Comment: thanks, but how do i convert string value date time format. It could be "30/08/2013 or 30-08-2013.

Comment: Take a look at the edit

Comment: Thanks, but something like startDate="2013/08/30" or "20.5.2013" or 02.9.2013 г. or "34-22-02".

Comment: Check out the edit. You can add more `else if`s for as many different characters as you need to split on.